# Ressources on how to find the appropiate algorithm for minimization problem?

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I have a Python function where I want to find the global minimum.

I am looking for a resource on how to choose the appropriate algorithm for it.

When looking at [scipy.optimize.minimize documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), I can find some not very specific statements like

- *has proven good performance even for non-smooth optimizations*
- *Suitable for large-scale problems*
- *recommended for medium and large-scale problems*

Apart from that I am unsure whether for my function [basinhopping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html) might be better or even [bayesian-optimization](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/auto_examples/bayesian-optimization.html). For the latter I am unsure whether that is only meant for machine learning cost functions or can be used generally.

I am looking for a [cheat sheet](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html) like
[image: see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html]

but just for minimization problems.

Does something like that already exist?
If not, how would I be able to choose the most appropriate algorithm based on my constraints (that are: time consuming to compute, 4 input variables, known boundaries)?

Comment: Some other interesting packages might also be: [facebook nevergrad](https://github.com/facebookresearch/nevergrad), [fmfn BayesianOptimization](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization), [trieste BayesianOptimization](https://github.com/secondmind-labs/trieste)

Comment: High-performance and global optimization typically don't go together, Note that basin-hopping is a heuristic: it may not find the global optimum.